# How can I calculate the area of a circle which I detected with cv2.HoughCircles()?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

guys,

I have written a program where I recognize circles with *cv2.HoughCircles()*. The code works too. Unfortunately I need the area of the circles for my project. But I don't know how to calculate this and my search on the internet was unsuccessful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png',0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,
                            param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

`i[0]` is the x position
`i[1]` is the y position
`i[2]` is the radius

Area is calculated with the formula `pi * r²`

So the area of each detected circle would be:

```
for i in circles[0,:]:
  area = 3.14159 * i[2] * i[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

From HoughCircles() you get a list of 'circles' which contains x, y, r of the circle. x, y are coordinates of the center and r is the radius.
From the radius you can calculate the area of the circle with:

A = PI * r^2